# how do I specify my image dimensions using css?

Tags: css

I have a result of 93% pagespeed and 88% yslow on gtmetrix, but 70% on this "Specify image dimensions". what should I do?

```
The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes.

http://www.cochlea.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ab_trans.png (Dimensions: 25 x 25)
http://www.cochlea.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/cochlear_trans.png (Dimensions: 25 x 25)
http://www.cochlea.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/medel_trans.png (Dimensions: 25 x 25)
http://www.cochlea.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cochleagold.png (Dimensions: 316 x 158)
http://www.cochlea.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/gmaps-25.png (Dimensions: 25 x 25)
http://www.cochlea.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/ta.png (Dimensions: 35 x 35)

<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ab_trans.png" alt="AB">
```

Comment: When you display those images in your page(s) are you specifying the dimensions? Where's your code?

Comment: I've had the exact height and weight before, but the same result. so I removed it to check, and still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, make sure you specify dimensions for your images.

Correct:

```
<img src="http://www.cochlea.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ab_trans.png" width="25" height="25" />
```

Incorrect (not *strictly* incorrect per say, but definitely less efficient - this is what pagespeed/yslow are complaining about):

```
<img src="http://www.cochlea.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ab_trans.png" />
```

Comment: Oops, seems like it's working now! thanks.